# .NET 2.0 application on windows server 2008 fails

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008

I have installed my .NET 2.0 application on windows server 2008. Its a ASP.NET application. But when I type the service url I get the following error

Compilation Error 
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: CS0016: Could not write to output file 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\medicserver\07c809be\c871d9f8\App_Web_menu.ascx.cdcab7d2.hxqoa_hn.dll' -- 'Access is denied. '

Source Error:

[No relevant source lines]

Source File:    Line: 0

---

I read other posts and gave the access to the temp ASP.NET folder to NEtwork service. I couldnt add ASP.NET machine account as i dont see the user in the system. In a normal windows xp system where it runs fine, i see that this temp folder has another user machinename/ASPNET. I dont see such user in the windows server 2008. I am new to windows server 2008 so any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Check the user that is running the IIS Application Pool for that website and assign write permissions to that user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in many situation uninstalling and installing .net framework again works that

run following command in cmd

Navigate to this folder from command prompt
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727

and then run the follwing command
aspnet_regiis -u
(uninstall) 
and then
aspnet_regiis -i
(install)

then reset iis
iisreset